# Ошибка установки nodegui (windows 10)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Хочу поставить [nodegui](https://docs.nodegui.org/) (windows 10)

Выполняю команды из дока по ссылке

Получаю:

```
npm install

> @nodegui/qode@2.0.4 postinstall E:\path\to\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode
> node install.js

internal/util.js:214
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at Object.promisify (internal/util.js:214:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\path\to\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode\src\downloader.js:10:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\path\to\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode\src\setup.js:5:22)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @nodegui/qode@2.0.4 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @nodegui/qode@2.0.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\path\to\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-18T12_38_46_755Z-debug.log
```

Пробовал гуглить (возможно плохо гуглил) - в основном речь шла о проблемах с gcc

У меня сначала стоял такой:

```
gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Попробовал поставить такой - тоже не дало результатов

```
realgcc.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Помогла установка CMake : https://cmake.org/download/